# How to create a new column with unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table TB_PRUEBAS has a column called "CltsVcdos" with several repeated customer's Id's. Now, I want to add a new column that shows me a 1 when the Id is unique, and 0 when the Id is repeated.

Part of the Query
[image]

That's what I want

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: (1) SQL tables are *unordered* and your desired results seem to depend on an ordering.  Is there a column that specifies the ordering?  (2) Your query has nothing to do with your sample data, so your question is quite confusing.

Comment: no image please. Please edit your question and include the query text here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Case When ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(  PARTITION BY CltsVcdos ORDER BY CltsVcdos ASC) ) =1)  then 1 else 0 end
```

You can Use above condition  to  get the UNIQUEVALUES.
Following example  explains it  further

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS](
    [CltsVcdos] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS] ([CltsVcdos]) VALUES (101)
INSERT [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS] ([CltsVcdos]) VALUES (101)
INSERT [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS] ([CltsVcdos]) VALUES (101)
INSERT [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS] ([CltsVcdos]) VALUES (102)
INSERT [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS] ([CltsVcdos]) VALUES (102)
INSERT [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS] ([CltsVcdos]) VALUES (104)


SELECT  
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CltsVcdos ASC) AS Row#,
[CltsVcdos],
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(  PARTITION BY CltsVcdos ORDER BY CltsVcdos ASC) ) As RepeatedRowNumber ,
Case When ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(  PARTITION BY CltsVcdos ORDER BY CltsVcdos ASC) ) =1)  then 1 else 0 end As UNIQUEVALUES
FROM [dbo].[TB_PRUEBAS] P
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have some kind of `identity` *columns* which specifies the ordering

```
select CltsVcdos,
        (case when count(CltsVcdos) over (partition by CltsVcdos by <identity_col>) > 1 
              then 0 else 1 end) as UniquValues
from TB_PRUEBAS
```